# pyotp OTP secret key format

Tags: python, one-time-password

I'm trying to programmatically generate OTP codes with pyotp, to login with headless browser, but I'm not sure how to handle the format of the shared secret key.

Usually the shared secret key is formatted like:
**ABCDEFGHIJKLM123**

But for the site I'm trying to login to the format is:
**ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRST UVWX YZ01 1234 5678 9ABC DEFG HIJK LMNO**

How can I use this shared secret key with pyotp to generate OTP code to login to a website?

I've tried converting it to base32, but either I'm doing something wrong with the conversion or it doesn't work.

Thanks!

code:

```
import pyotp
import time

totp = pyotp.TOTP("ABCDEFGHIJKLM123")

while True:
   print('current otp:', totp.now())
   time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You say you tried - what did you try, and how did it fail?

Comment: I encoded "ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRST UVWX YZ01 1234 5678 9ABC DEFG HIJK LMNO" to base32 ("IFBEGRBAIVDEOSBAJFFEWTBAJVHE6UBAKFJFGVBAKVLFOWBALFNDAMJAGEZDGNBAGU3DOOBAHFAUEQZAIRCUMRZAJBEUUSZAJRGU4TY=") using https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base32_encode.html

it didn't work as in that the OTP code generated is not correct.

Comment: Perhaps try removing the spaces? If that doesn't work, I think we'll need more details about your code.

Comment: Removing spaces didn't work. I added code in the post.
To elaborate; for many sites I get a 2FA key like "ABCDEFGHIJKLM123" and for those the code works fine and generates the correct code. 
But from Amazon I get a different format shared key ("ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP QRST UVWX YZ01 1234 5678 9ABC DEFG HIJK LMNO"), but I"m ont sure how to use this key with above code.

Comment: Looking to see if anyone has a solution for the longer shared keys.  Been doing a little research and experimenting myself to no avail. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```py
import pyotp
totp = pyotp.TOTP("MY CODE WITH SPACES".replace(' ',''))
print("Current OTP:", totp.now())
```